# CDK - Can't use scaleOnCpuUtilization

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm trying to write something simple in CDK (typescript) but can't get this to work:

```
const cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, "eksCluster", clusterProps);
// Scale up EKS Cluster when above 80% CPU
        cluster.defaultCapacity!.scaleOnCpuUtilization('up', {
            targetUtilizationPercent: 80
        });
```

Everytime I run `cdk ls` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scaleOnCpuUtilization' of undefined
```

How am I supposed to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It says:

```
property 'scaleOnCpuUtilization' of undefined
```

Which should mean `cluster.defaultCapacity!` is null. I am not a JavaScript programmer but what is this `!`?

Comment: The `!` is a typescript thing. It means the `defaultCapacity` can potentially be a null value. However it will not work without the `!` either. I think I might be actually using the wrong method because I found this in the `legacy` section of the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-eks-legacy-readme.html

Here is the new documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-eks-readme.html